# Perl- Extract each line from a txt file and store into different variables

Tags: perl

I readin a txt file using a perl script, but im wondering how to store each line from the txt file into a different variable in the perl script using pattern matching. I can match a line using ~^>gi , but it displays both lines from the txt file with >gi (i.e line 1 & 3), also i want to read the two separate DNA sequences into different variables. Consider my example below.

file.txt

```
 >gi102939
 GATCTATC
 >gi123453
 CATCGACA
```

the perl script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

open (MYFILE, 'file.txt');

@array = <MYFILE>;
($first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth) = @array;
chomp $first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth;
print "Contents:\n @array";

 if (@array =~ /^>gi/) 
 {  
   print "$first";
 }

close (MYFILE);
```

Comment: Your request to save the lines into different variables seems odd to me.  I think you would be better loading data into a hash, where the keys are gi102939, gi123453 and the values are GATCTATC and CATCGACA.  Please indicate if 1) the keys (lines starting with >) are unique or not, and also what the intention of the pattern match is - it DOES match both lines, what did you intend it to do?

Comment: im a beginner to Perl, and i'm not familiar with BioPerl.

Comment: the lines starting with > are unique, as the example shows.

Comment: i want to be able to read in each line that starts with >gi, the problem is each gi identifer is unique.                              Also i want to read in each DNA sequence from the file(in this case 2) into a different variable because i have code to compare the sequences. which is why i need to store each DNA sequence into a variable. thanks for the help

Comment: You have already achieved what you describe by reading the file into an array. The identifiers are in `$array[0]`, `$array[2]` etc. and the sequences are in `$array[1]`, `$array[3]` etc. But you haven#t explained the *problem* you are solving. Programs aren't written to get data into variables - that is a means to an end. What is your goal? Given the input file you have shown, what result do you want?

Comment: sry for the confusion, yes the lines are readin into the arrays $array[1], Sarray[2] etc but thats reading the file line by line. whereas i want to read the file and recognise that >gi is line 1 or a DNA sequence is on line 2 and extract this info into different variables or an array. the above txt file is an example,  another file.txt could have more of these lines with a descriptor line followed by a DNA sequence.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for the help guys. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `>gi..` are unique in the input, populate a hash where each key is associated with a sequence:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl    
use warnings;
use strict;
my %hash;
my $last;
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  if (/^>gi/) {
    $last = $_; 
  } else {
    $hash{$last} = $_; 
  }
}
foreach my $k (keys %hash) {
  print "$k => $hash{$k}\n";
}
__DATA__

>gi102939
GATCTATC
>gi123453
CATCGACA
```

Answer (score 1):

Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your program, and declare your variables using `my` at their first point of use. This applies epecially when you are asking for help, as doing so can frequently reveal simlpe problems that could otherwise be overlooked.

As it stands, your program will read the file into `@array` and print it out. The test `if (@array =~ /^>gi/) { ... }` will force scalar context on the array, and so compare the number of elements in the array, presumably `5`, with the regex pattern and fail.

What exactly are you trying to achieve? Reading a file into an array puts each line into a different scalar variables - the variables being the elements of the array

Comment: im a beginner to Perl, so im not really sure if its possible. but im trying to - extract the content of the text file, then extract the descriptor lines, using the identifiers >gi at the start of the line. but i want to store each identifer line in a separate variable in the perl script after reading them from the file.txt. then i want to extract each DNA sequence from the file and store them in separate variables, because i have code to compare 2 DNA sequences, once they are separated into different variables. Is this possible??? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner reads the database and extracts one element:

```
perl < file.txt -e '@array=<>;chomp @array;%hash=@array;print $hash{">gi102939"}'
```

result:

```
GATCTATC
```